# @Html.DropDownListFor - How to set color for the selected item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, colors, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedvalue

I now know (thanks @Shyju) that I can set the color of a particular item in a @Html.DropDownListFor using:

`$(function(){
$("#fancySelect").find("option:contains('Deleted')").css('color','red');
});`

However once selected the item's color reverts to the default black. How can I make the selected item's color stay red?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 $("#fancySelect").change(function () {
     if($("#fancySelect option:selected").text() == 'Deleted'){
            $("#fancySelect").css('color','red');
     }else{
            $("#fancySelect").css('color','black');
     }  
 });
```

Comment: That does not work. Nothing happens even if I change the else to be a different color.